# iPython Notebook not printing function interface

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I recently upgraded iPython through anaconda (anaconda version 2.2.0... iPython version 3.1.0) and the newest version of iPython Notebooks don't print the API documentation for modules in a little dropdown box anymore. Is this still supported and was it just on by default in previous versions and off by default now.

Is this something that needs to be edited in the ipython-notebook.config file in the profile that is loaded?

It's super useful to reference when you're writing code in the iPython notebook and I'd like to get it back. Anyone know what to do here?

Comment: hmm perhaps it's related to qt support? using the qtconsole (ipython qtconsole) works as it used to but the notebook is now not showing the documentation

Answer (score 0):

you can find answer and even more at [IPython Notebook quick tour](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/A%20quick%20tour%20of%20IPython%20Notebook.ipynb)

just press shift+tab

- one time - short help
- second time - full help
- third time - tooltip will linger for 10 seconds while you type
- fourth time - bigger help at browser bottom

Comment: thanks! that works and it's actually better than before because the documentation doesn't get in the way.